# Is there anything I can use as a proxy to connect to a SQL Server (on TLS v1.2) from a legacy application which uses only TLS v1?

Tags: sql-server, database, tls1.2, freetds, stunnel

We have a legacy application (vendor product) which we don't have source for, which connects to a MS SQL Server 2008 using TLS v1. Now there is a mandate to move all connectivity to TLS v1.2. We are able to upgrade SQL Server to a version supporting TLS v1.2, but not the legacy application.

I have tried using stunnel running on the same host as the legacy app (so the legacy app connects to stunnel to route the connection to the db). This doesn't seem to work as SQL Server uses TDS to negotiate instead of TLS. So the connection doesn't go thru.

Is there anything else I can try to make it work? Or if someone has been able to make stunnel work with SQL Server?

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: What kind of server does the legacy application run on? Does it only support SQL Server, or is ODBC an option?